# How can I navigate to other fragment from ViewPager's fragment using Jetpack Navigation Component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I have an App.
It based on Android Jetpack Navigation component and has Tab UI with ViewPager.

For example, there are fragments as Tab UI. (Not BottomNavigation UI)

- MainFragment: This holds 3 Tab fragments as Tab & ViewPager.
- DetailsFragment

These 2 Fragments exist on nav_graph.xml.

and others:

- TabAFragment
- TabBFragment
- TabCFragment

These 3 Fragments doesn't exist on nav_graph.xml

What I want to know is how can I navigate from TabXFragment to DetailsFragment.

Actually, navigation is not difficult.
It is same.
I can do navigate just calling "findNavController.navigate()".

But the problem is the "back" button.

When I touch the "back" button on DetailsFragment, it shows weird screen.
Just the white screen.
There are no TabView.

I expected that it shows TabXFragment.
But it doesn't...

So I solved this issue using Activity instead of DetailsFragment.
But I want to know how can I handle this issue...

(Sorry for my poor English skill)

Comment: Do you mind sharing how you did the navigation from the ViewPager to the DetailsFragment? When I set it up, the fragment manager complains the fragment was already added and crashes. I think it's adding it once for the Adapter, and another time from the nav_graph.

How to set up the navgraph to understand that Tab A can lead to DetailsFrag while Tab B can also do the same, or have a different action?

Answer (score 0):

I used this method and it works for me

Simply use `ViewPager2` in MainFragment like the below code

```
 val adapter =ViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager,lifecycle)
 adapter.addFragment(TabAFragment(),"A")
 adapter.addFragment(TabAFragment(),"B")
 adapter.addFragment(TabAFragment(),"C")
 binding.viewpager.adapter =adapter
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Then in your navigation graph create a route from MainFragment to DetailsFragment

And in your ViewPager fragments (like TabAFragment) simply navigate from MainFragment to DetailsFragment

And don't forget to add an adapter like below

```
class ViewPagerAdapter (manager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) :  FragmentStateAdapter(manager,lifecycle ){
    private val fragmentList : MutableList<Fragment> =ArrayList()
    private val titleList : MutableList<String> =ArrayList()
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return fragmentList.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return  fragmentList[position]
    }


    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String){
        fragmentList.add(fragment)
        titleList.add(title)
    }

    fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return titleList[position]
    }
}
```

Finally in your DetailsFragment just use below code to finish current fragment

```
findNavController().popBackStack()
```